# How to dequeue a stylesheet by src, not handle?

Tags: css, regex

I'm trying to develop a Wordpress plugin that will dequeue/deregister *Font Awesome* stylesheets added to a theme by certain plugins that users may install, if the theme already make use of *Font Awesome*.

In other words: if an administrator uses a theme that has **Font Awesome** font-awesome.css (or font-awesome.min.css) and he uses 2 plugins that make use of *Font Awesome* too, the administrator will ended up with 3 font-awesome.css (or font-awesome.min.css) stylesheets loaded.

Is there a way to check if the *Font Awesome* stylesheet is already loaded by the theme and if so, automatically dequeue/deregister all plugins *Font Awesome* stylesheets, before the theme enqueue it?

The solution I have in mind is something like this (pseudo code):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'no_more_fontawesome', 999 );
function no_more_fontawesome() {
    if ( src_contain ('font-awesome.css') || src_contain('font-awesome.min.css') ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( that has font-awesome.css or font-awesome.min.css in src);
    }
```

A solution might be a regex check in src for the expressions *font-awesome.css* and *font-awesome.min.css* but how to achieve this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you are wrong. If all plugins and themes that use Font Awsome are enqueuing the styles properly, Wordpress will enqueue only one file and will take care of dependencies. The registration and enqueue system in Wordpress is just great.

Comment: @cybmeta in most cases plugin developers tend to use different names as a handle or prefix their handle with plugin prefix e.g _mp_font-awesome_, _fontawesome_, _font-awesome_ etc..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for existing of multiple stylesheet handles then dequeue them using wp\_style\_is?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145782/how-to-check-for-existing-of-multiple-stylesheet-handles-then-dequeue-them-using)

Comment: @Pieter Goosen They are totally different questions: one about dequeue styles based on src and another based of known handle. Are you serious?

Comment: My opinion, still the same question as both invlove the same exact stylesheets

Comment: @Pieter Goosen are you sure you have read the questions carefully and completely?

Comment: @Pieter Goosen, if two questions invlove the same stylesheets, you mark them as duplicate? No offense, I just wonder how your mind works ...

Comment: We all have our own opinions, whether right or wrong. We aren't here to stone each other to death about a disagreement about what we feel what is the same or not. I do apologize if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about a rare scenario. "font-awsome" is the expected name that all plugins and themes should be using as handle. If the developer has not changed the source code of font awsome CSS file, there is no reason to change the name of the handle. Anyway, you can check the global $wp_styles object and make a regex in the src value of each enqueued style:

```
function cybmeta_dequeue_fontawsome() {

    global $wp_styles;
    // we use preg_match to find only the following patterns as exact matches, to prevent other stylesheets that contain font-awesome expression to be also dequeued
    $patterns = array(
        'font-awesome.css',
        'font-awesome.min.css'
        );

    $regex = '/(' .implode('|', $patterns) .')/i';

    foreach( $wp_styles -> registered as $registered ) {

        if( preg_match( $regex, $registered->src) ) {
            wp_dequeue_style( $registered->handle );
            // FA was dequeued, so here we need to enqueue it again from the location we want (cdn in our code)
            wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
        }
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cybmeta_dequeue_fontawsome' );
```

Comment: Thanks @cybmeta, your propossed code is work great but it  dequeue the _Font Awesome_ loadded by the theme too. The challange here is to check first if the Font Awesome stylesheet is already loaded by the theme, and only then dequeue extra stylesheets added by plugins. So, could you improve your answer? However, I will accept your answer since it provides a simple and clean solution than I expected.

Comment: about handle's name, be my guest to search for _Font Awesome_ in WP repo and you will be surprised to find that any of the top 10 plugins haven't the same handle name. They called them as _mp_font-awesome_, _fontawesome_, _font-awesome_, etc..

Comment: As I said, I think that changing the handle name for third party libraries is a bad thing and there is no reason to do it. You can see how doing that cause problems that you are trying to solve. Developers should follow naming standards.

Comment: So need to dequeue all font-awsome except from the theme? From a theme in general or from a specific theme? See edited answer.

Comment: you're right but we can't force plugin developers to follows the best practices or WP standards. Btw, can you improve the _preg_match_ snippet to search only for _font-awesome.css_ or _font-awesome.min.css_ (exact matches) since several plugins load extra styesheets like _font-awesome-social_ or _font-awesome-ext.css_? I don't want these stylesheets to be dequeued too. Thank you!

Comment: We need to dequeue all font-awsome except from a _public_ theme, not a specific one.

Comment: Maybe checking for "themes" in the src of the styles can do the job. See edited answer.

Comment: Unfortunately no, checking for "themes" in the src of the styles doesn't work for me so can you rollback your answer to be able to accept your answer please? What would really help me would be the _preg_match_ snippet to search only for font-awesome.css or _font-awesome.min.css_ as exact matches, not for any other variants such as _font-awesome-ext.css_ or so. Thank you.

Comment: How about the edited code? Do you think it make sense?

Comment: @s_ha_dum your opinion is also worth a lot to me :)

Comment: @Alexan : the answers you are getting look to be on the right track, though I haven't tested anything. Does this solution not work? Does it have bugs?

Comment: @s_ha_dum I just tested the code and it seems to work. Answer accepted! Thanks all.