# Check and dequeue if multiple stylesheets exists using wp_style_is?

Tags: css

I need to dequeue styes for 3 plugins that load the same font stylesheet so i come up with the following function that of course not working:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_by_handles', 999);
function dequeue_by_handles() {
    $handle = array(
        'fontawesome',
        'font-awesome',
        'font-awesome-style'
        );

    if( wp_style_is( $handle, $list = 'enqueued' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( $handle );
    }
}
```

Please note that firstly I need to check if a stylesheet handle exist then dequeue it.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice. Rather file an edit to add additional info to the original question. I've already voted to close [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145773/how-to-dequeue-a-stylesheet-by-src-not-handle).

Comment: @Pieter Goosen They are totally different questions: one about dequeue styles based on src and another based of known handle. Are you serious?

Comment: I also think you should edit the other question and add more information there. You are asking here and there about the exact same problem but with different point of view: Dequeue based on src or based on handle to solve the exact same problem. Also, a comment in the proposed answer in the other question would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested this, but I imagine it is because you are passing an array to the $handle variable in your `wp_style_is()` function and not a string.

Maybe try looping through the array so you pass it a single string to check against each time.

Something Like this...

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_by_handles', 999);

function dequeue_by_handles() {

    $handles = array(
        'fontawesome',
        'font-awesome',
        'font-awesome-style'
        );

    foreach ($handles as $handle) {

        if ( wp_style_is( $handle, $list = 'enqueued' ) ) {
            wp_dequeue_style( $handle );
        }
    }
}
```